# Regex to match words may or may not contain ascii chars that starts with a certain char

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match the words in a string that starts with a certain character, say #, and may contain chars not in low-ascii.
Like following string:

`var x = "#tür asas asd #ert #açılım"`

`x.match(/#\w+/g)` returns `["#t", "#ert", "#a"]`

it breaks at the point it finds a non english character.

What can be the extension to my regex to include the words with non-english chars.

I use this codes in JavaScript.

Comment: use `#\p{L}` in your regex expression

Comment: Yeah, `#[\p{L}0-9_]+` but with `XRegExp`, not `RegExp`.

Comment: Javascript regex has no support of Unicodes properties. Will `/#\S+/g` work for you?

Comment: @Wiktor I think JavaScript does not have XregExp.

Comment: @Işık See [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/).